# Bind a combo box in a datagrid to an observable collection

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid

So I have a data grid (datagrid A) and the item source is bound to an observable collection, inside this observable collection is a property that is a list.

What I am trying to do is populate this list from another data grid that is bound to an observable collection.

In the other data grid (datagrid B) they user types in various information. In the first column is a string field called Name.

So what I need to do is in Datagrid A, populate a combo box from the user typed entries in Datagrid B, so they can select from the various names they have typed.

I thought I could just bind the combo box item propety to DataGrid B's collection and set the display member path but this fails with "Could not find governing framework element"

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set the dataContext property on dataGrid A?

Comment: some code you can post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out after awhile.

You can set a collectionViewSource in the window.Resources xaml and then reference that in the itemsource data grid

```
 <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SourceList" Source="{Binding object}"></CollectionViewSource>
```